# Comparar data e hora

Tags: c, arduino

Em C tenho a lib time.h para manipular data e hora, já no Arduino a classe DateTime que implementa alguns metodos.

Não estou encontrando, mesmo que seja na unha, como comparar data e hora, por exemplo:

```
if ( dt >= checkin )
```

onde dt é a data e hora atual e checking uma data do sistema, como comparar?

Comment: esse `dt` e o `checkin` são de que tipo ? Como foram inicializados ?

Comment: Nossa desculpe esqueci, são DateTime então posso usar o method unixtime() né?

Comment: O ideal é mostrar como foram declaradas e inicializadas as variaveis. Incluir o trecho de código relevante

Answer (score 0):

Você pode converter as duas datas para um formato de numero com a função `mktime` e compará-los.